# How to count how many Occurences of the word i have in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

How to count how many Occurences of the word i have in an ArrayList? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Don't make a list of characters, make a list of `String`(s). Use `split("\\s+")` to split each line on whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static int findMatches(List<Character> text, List<Character> pattern) {
    int n = text.size();
    int m = pattern.size();
    int count = 0;  // tracks number of matches found

    for (int i = 0; i <= n - m; i++) { 
        int k = 0;
        while (k < m && text.get(i + k) == pattern.get(k))
        k++;
        if (k == m) { // if we reach the end of the pattern
            k = 0;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to only find how many matches and you don't need to know positions try using this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("hello.txt"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String str = null;
    while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
        builder.append(str);
    }

    String fileString = builder.toString();
    String match = "wordToMatch";
    String[] split = fileString.split(match);
    System.out.println(split.length - 1);//finds amount matching exact sentance
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the number of times one string occurs in another is fairly trivial so it might be best to read your file into a string rather than a list of characters if all you are going to do is search it

```
int matches = 0;
for (int index = text.indexOf(target); index != -1; index = text.indexOf(target, index + 1))
    matches++;
```

However most efficient search algorithms are going to require you to create an index as you read the input - something like a `Map<String,List<Integer>>` that can quickly find a list of word positions for a given word.

For example (using Java 8):

```
List<String> words; // ordered list of words read from the text file
Map<String, List<Integer>> index = IntStream.range(0, words.size())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(words::get));
```

Then searching for a word becomes trivial (e.g. `index.get(word).size()` is the number of occurences). Searching for a phrase is not much harder: you break it into words then filter the index values for consecutive word positions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<String>` instead of `List<Character>`.  After that you can either brute force the occurrence or use Java 8's streams and filter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList() {{
        add("one");
        add("two");
        add("one");
        add("one");
        add("two");
        add("one");
        add("two");
        add("three");
        add("one");
        add("one");
    }};

    String wordToSearch = "one";

    int occurrence = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.equals(wordToSearch)) {
            occurrence++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Brute force: " + occurrence);
    System.out.println("Streams    : " + words.stream()
            .filter(word -> word.equalsIgnoreCase(wordToSearch)).count());
}
```

Results:

```
Brute force: 6
Streams    : 6
```